# resolve a previously failing url without editing resolv.conf

Tags: domain-name-system, ping, resolv.conf

I want to ping a some website from my machine. But currently its failing to resolve

```
ubuntu % nslookup somewebsite.in                                                                                         
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 169.254.169.254, trying next server
Server:         10.240.0.1
Address:        10.240.0.1#53

** server can't find somewebsite.in: SERVFAIL
```

I want to resolve it just a few times to run `mtr` tests without editing `resolv.conf`. How is it possible, if at all?

Comment: Use `nslookup` or `host` from a different machine. Use this IP address with `mtr`. No need to resolve anything on the troubled machine itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [dig](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dig) and provide and alternate DNS server

```
dig @8.8.8.8 example.com
```

where @8.8.8.8 is the DNS server fr dig to use (in this case Google's public server)

Or you could use [host](http://linux.die.net/man/1/host) and provide and alternate DNS server

```
host example.com 8.8.8.8
```